# If screen is lower than 600, on click expand search bar and hide the rest of elements

Tags: jquery

I have a search bar that is closed when screen is less than 600px, in same line with another 2 elements (a menu + a shopping cart).
When I click on the search bar it has to expand and also the 2 elements must dissapear. When I click the x and close the search bar (or outside), it must revert (shrink + show the 2 elements).

These are the problems I have:

1. Search bar must close as well if I close outside it, not just on x
2. Elements must remain hidden until search bar is closed. So if I click on the search button to perform the search + click to input terms of search, the 2 elements must remain hidden - right now they show again

Demo https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pQebge

```
<div class="htr-top">
MENU
</div>
<ul class="cart-area">
CART
</ul>
<div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="input-holder">
        <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Type to search" />
        <button class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"><span></span></button>
    </div>
    <span class="close" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"></span>
</div>

body {
   background: #212129;
}

::selection {
   background: #212129;
}
.htr-top, .cart-area {
  display:inline-block;
}
.search-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top:50%;
    left:50%;*/
   display:inline-block;
}
.search-wrapper.active {}

.search-wrapper .input-holder {    
    height: 70px;
    width:70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border-radius:6px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder {
    width:450px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-input {
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding:0px 70px 0 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-family:"Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    color:#FFF;
    transform: translate(0, 60px);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-input {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 10px);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:6px;
    background: #FFF;
    padding:0px;
    outline:none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span {
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650);
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon span {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before, .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
    position: absolute; 
    content:'';
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before {
    width: 4px;
    height: 11px;
    left: 9px;
    top: 18px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #FE5F55;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border: 4px solid #FE5F55;
}
.search-wrapper .close {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:24px;
    right:20px;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.search-wrapper.active .close {
    right:-50px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.search-wrapper .close::before, .search-wrapper .close::after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    background: #FE5F55;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::before {
    width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::after {
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
}


function searchToggle(obj, evt){
    var container = $(obj).closest('.search-wrapper');
        if(!container.hasClass('active')){
            container.addClass('active');
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        else if(container.hasClass('active') && $(obj).closest('.input-holder').length == 0){
            container.removeClass('active');
            // clear input
            container.find('.search-input').val('');
        }
}

$('.search-wrapper').on('click', function(){
            $('.cart-area,.htr-top').toggle();
        });

function checkWidth(init)
{
    /*If browser resized, check width again */
    if ($(window).width() > 600) {
        $('.search-wrapper').addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        if (!init) {
            $('.search-wrapper').removeClass('active');
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWidth(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$('.search-wrapper').on('click', function(){` from code and use `$('.cart-area,.htr-top').toggle();` inside `searchToggle` function as below code.

**Update**

Added `$("html").on("click", function(e) {` function to close search box on click outside of `search` box.

```js
function searchToggle(obj, evt) {
  var container = $(obj).closest(".search-wrapper");
  if (!container.hasClass("active")) {
    container.addClass("active");
    $(".cart-area,.htr-top").toggle();
    $(".search-input").focus();
    evt.preventDefault();
  } else if (container.hasClass("active") && $(obj).closest(".input-holder").length == 0) {
    container.removeClass("active");
    // clear input
    container.find(".search-input").val("");
    $(".cart-area,.htr-top").toggle();
  }
}
$("html").on("click", function(e) {
  var container = $(".search-wrapper");
  if (container.hasClass("active") && $(e.target).closest(".search-wrapper").length == 0) {
    container.removeClass("active");
    container.find(".search-input").val("");
    $(".cart-area,.htr-top").toggle();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #212129;
}

::selection {
  background: #212129;
}

.htr-top,
.cart-area {
  display: inline-block;
}

.search-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top:50%;
    left:50%;*/
  display: inline-block;
}

.search-wrapper.active {}

.search-wrapper .input-holder {
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.search-wrapper.active .input-holder {
  width: 450px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
}

.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px 70px 0 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  transform: translate(0, 60px);
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-input {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(0, 10px);
}

.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650);
}

.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon span {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before,
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}

.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before {
  width: 4px;
  height: 11px;
  left: 9px;
  top: 18px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #FE5F55;
}

.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 4px solid #FE5F55;
}

.search-wrapper .close {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 24px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.search-wrapper.active .close {
  right: -50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.search-wrapper .close::before,
.search-wrapper .close::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  background: #FE5F55;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.search-wrapper .close::before {
  width: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0px;
}

.search-wrapper .close::after {
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="htr-top">
  MENU
</div>
<ul class="cart-area">
  CART
</ul>
<div class="search-wrapper">
  <div class="input-holder">
    <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Type to search" />
    <button class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"><span></span></button>
  </div>
  <span class="close" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yupeee...Works great. Can we colapse the search and show the 2 elements if we click outside of search (not just the x button)?

Comment: Updated my answer to close search box on click outside of search box.

Comment: Works in the demo you provided but in my site it makes the header elements dissapear on click outside the page. I am using for desktop mode the search bar as active so expanded and when screen is lower than 600px it has the active class removed and so it shows collapsed till i click on search button. The code for page resize is specified on top of thread. Thank you anyway for your help

Comment: On desktop browsers the menu works ok. On mobile phone, the moment i click on input field to enter the text and the keyboard shows, the search bar closes. Any way to prevent this on mobile phones?